# Process XML using XPATH in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, xpath

I need some help in processing XML using XPATH in SPARK SQL. 
We have XML stored in a Database COLUMN. We need to process the XML and store  it in a relational table.

Below is the sample SQL to read XML but it does not produce the desired results. I need all the nodes under `<b>`... should 3 rows.. not sure how to get the results... appreciate if someone can help

```
SELECT xpath_string('<a><b>b1</b><b>b2</b><b>b3</b><c>c1</c><c>c2</c></a>','/a/b');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behaviour if you look at the documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#xpath_string

`xpath_string(xml, xpath)` returns the text contents of the first node that matches your xpath.

To get all matching values into an array use xpath. Make sure you add the text() function at the end or you'll get a beautiful stack trace.

```
%sql
SELECT xpath('<a><b>b1</b><b>b2</b><b>b3</b><c>c1</c><c>c2</c></a>','/a/b/text()');
```

Returns

```
["b1","b2","b3"]
```